# View Frames change after being loaded

Tags: ios

It seems like I may be misunderstanding something. I've got an iPad app which is fullscreen and doesn't have a status bar or anything else. It's also always in landscape mode, so I don't need to worry about portrait. I'm creating a view programmatically using the correct frame, but when the view actually loads and is displayed the frame seems to be different.

Here is the code I use to generate the view (I add more things to the view below, but they aren't related to my issue):

```
- (void)loadView{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 768.0)];

    backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [backgroundImage setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
    [self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
}
```

In view did appear, I NSLog the frame of self.view and get `{{-128, -128}, {1024, 768}}`. The size is correct but the origin has changed. Just to see what would happen, I tried initializing the view with an origin of 128, 128 - this produced a frame of `{{0, -256}, {1024, 768}}` which I can't explain either.

Can anyone tell me what the heck is happening? I tried playing around with setting autoresize masks and such, and it didn't really change anything. I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2):

All the `UIViews`' correct geometry is only available in and after the `viewWillAppear:` method. Before it, the view hierarchy's geometry has not been set and the values are inaccurate. If you need to know, change, calculate frames you should not do it before `viewWillAppear:` method.
**UPDATE:**
Override the `-loadView` method to initialize `self.view` with an `UIView`. If you are using a nib file this is done automatically for you and you should not override this method. Real view geometry is not available in this method.
`-viewDidLoad` is where the view hierarchy is being setup. This is the place where you typically initialize your subviews and add them in your `self.view`. You can perform some heavier operations as long as they don't require multithreading. View geometry is also not available in this method - autoresizing masks still won't have effect here and you can't count on `frame` properties.
`-viewWillAppear:` is the place where everything is setup correctly, views are resized - use this method if you want to calculate and set additional geometry, `frame` properties are correct. Perform only lightweight operations here as this method should not block the main thread and it should execute as fast as it can. 
Same is for `viewDidAppear:`.

Comment: Just doesn't make sense - how come a view loaded from a nib can have its geometry set correctly when loaded, but when a view is created in code (which gets all set up at the same time as when the nib would be loaded) we can't set any of the frames until way later in the loading process?

Comment: The general practice is in `loadView` you only initialize `self.view` you can still initialize it with a hardcoded frame, but the autoresizing masks won't have any effect before `viewWillAppear:` method and you can't count on them in `viewDidLoad` because in this method the view hierarchy is being set up either from the nib file or manually. I will update my answer about those methods and what and where should be done.